# Hi I've written a query in mysql (that works) that I'd like to execute on oracle sql developer, so I am trying to write it in pl/sql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

**This is the query i am trying to replicate**

```
SELECT (
        CASE
            WHEN City like '%Berlin' and CustomerName like '%kiste'
                     THEN "CORRECT"
                  ELSE "INCORRECT"
             END) as Result, CustomerName, City
FROM Customers
```

Basically, this would display a new 'result' column where if the values match would display correct else incorrect.

**How do I script this in pl/sql? As i can't find a direct equivalent for the case statement**

Comment: This SQL statement is valid in Oracle as well as long as you replace double-quotes with single-quotes. Btw, get rid of the redundant brackets wrapping CASE WHEN..END expression.

Comment: What makes you think that Oracle doesn't support `CASE` expressions? Is it the error message you got in Oracle? If so, your request should contain this error essage.

Answer (score 1):

You want to write this in Oracle SQL, not in PL/SQL, which is a programming language built-into the Oracle database.

Your query is incorrect. You are using double quotes for two of the string literals which is not allowed in SQL. MySQL lets this pass under certain conditions.

So, to get the query straight, both in Oracle and MySQL, use single quotes for strings:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN city LIKE '%Berlin' AND customername LIKE '%kiste'
    THEN 'CORRECT'
    ELSE 'INCORRECT'
  END AS result,
  customername,
  city
FROM customers;
```

(I also removed the superfluous parentheses and got the upper/lower case consistent by writing all keywords in upper case.)